# Afnetworking 2.0 XML Serializer

Tags: objective-c, xml, afnetworking

I would like to list all files in a S3 Bucket, using AFNeworking with Ono XML Serializer, and store each filename (XML Contents Key) in a `NSMUtableArray`.

How can I access each XML->Contents->Key? It is always returning null.

---

XML:

```
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <Name>bucket</Name>
    <Prefix/>
    <Marker/>
    <MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
    <IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
    <Contents>
        <Key>Hugo Kant - Hittin' The Bottle.mp3</Key>
        <LastModified>2015-03-27T20:46:16.000Z</LastModified>
        <ETag>"f6b5204b704e0d648862310ed25a9900"</ETag>
        <Size>3774979</Size>
        <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
    </Contents>
    <Contents>
        <Key>Uppermost - Flow.mp3</Key>
        <LastModified>2015-03-27T20:46:16.000Z</LastModified>
        <ETag>"a1826cbac087042445576bf94de1e911"</ETag>
        <Size>4109324</Size>
        <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
    </Contents>
</ListBucketResult>
```

---

Afnetworking:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFOnoResponseSerializer XMLResponseSerializer];
[manager GET:@"https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, ONOXMLDocument *responseDocument) {

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (ONOXMLElement *element in [responseDocument.rootElement childrenWithTag:@"Contents"] ) {
        // Output Element (working)
        NSLog(@"%@", element);

        // Output Null (not working)
        NSLog(@"%@", element[@"Key"]);

        [array addObject:element[@"Key"]];
} failure:nil];
```